# Flutter 2: maxLength inside the textfield without using onChanged

Tags: flutter, textfield

I am trying to find a way to use maxLength and put it inside of the textfield to have a nice rendering. However, I don't want to use the onChanged parameter because I would have to use a setState, but this not the good way to use it.

The parameter maxLength from the flutter's textfield is designed to do not update the state, so that every statefull widgets don't have to rebuild.

So I would like to put the `0/50` inside, at the end of the textfield, on the same line as Title.

From this :

[image]

To this :

[image]

So somebody have an idea of how to do it without using the parameter onChanged ?

Does flutter has implemented this functionality ?

Answer (score -1):

Try with this, hope you get a solution.

```
TextField(
  maxLength: 250,
  buildCounter: (_, {currentLength, maxLength, isFocused}) => Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
    child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(currentLength.toString() + "/" + maxLength.toString())),
  ),
)
```

Also, Try with this,

```
  TextField(
          controller: nameController,
              maxLength: 60,
               prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.account_circle,
                color: Colors.black45,
              ),
              
          ),
```

Comment: No, not like that, "a way to use maxLength and put it inside of the textfield".
The question wasn't maybe enough explained, I updated it by using a another picture.